# jenkins multi job phase conditions

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins that acts like a parent job, which will be running in the master. In addition two more jobs, which is like a child of the master job.
When the master job is triggered, based on the platforms it will initiate the child jobs. The child jobs will be running in different nodes like windows and mac slaves. for example if the given platform is windows the child job which is in the windows slave should run and vice versa. I have given the condition like when the platform is not equal to null, trigger the child job. Where the platform is extended choice parameter in master job.

The condition is evaluated as "false". Is the condition correct ?

Here i am stuck to move forward...!
Helps Appreciated..!! [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [NodeLabel Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)

Use **Label** parameter and give your Slave's label name.

You can use and configure as many slave nodes by using this plugin.

Comment: Do i need to set the node & label params for master job or in slave jobs? the platforms value will be given as input in master job based on the value it should pick the child job and act accordingly. platforms may contains the values like "windows" only or "mac" only or both. if it is both then both of the child jobs should run, else any one of the job relative to the node should run. This is the use case, so is it possible to solve by using node & label parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the windows_node_platform is not a valid environment variable.

Check the environment variables you have (Manage Jenkins > System information)

I have not used jenkins on windows, but on my linux server, my TERM environment is "linux"